# SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Unsupported Media Type when accessing Java web-service from PHP

Tags: java, php, zend-framework, soap, web-services

I'm trying to connect to a Java web-service using the `Zend_Soap_Client` from the Zend Framework v1.9.0:

```
<?php
include( 'Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php');
$autoloader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
$client = new Zend_Soap_Client('https://webservice.com/webservice-war/webservice?wsdl'
    , array('encoding'=> 'UTF-8'));

try{
    $result = $client->find_customer(array('username' => 'user', 
                         'password' => '123'), array('city' => 'some city'));
} catch(Exception $e){
    echo $e;
}

echo '<pre>' . $client->getLastRequestHeaders() . '</pre>'; 
?>
```

Outputs:

```
SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Unsupported Media Type in 
/Library/ZendFramework-1.9.0/library/Zend/Soap/Client.php:937 
Stack trace: 
 #0 [internal function]:
SoapClient->__doRequest('_doRequest(Object(Zend_Soap_Client_Common),
    '__doRequest('__soapCall('find_customer', Array, NULL, NULL, Array) 
 #6 [internal function]:  
 Zend_Soap_Client->__call('find_customer', Array) 
 #7 /Users/webservicetest/index.php(8): 
 Zend_Soap_Client->find_customer(Array, Array) 
 #8 {main}

POST /webservice-war/webservice HTTP/1.1
Host: webservice.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: PHP-SOAP/5.2.6
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8; action=""
Content-Length: 315
```

Any idea what could be wrong? The url is correct, since I get the availible functions when calling

```
$client->getFunctions()
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

According to [this listing](http://www.w3.org/TR/soap12-part2/#tabreqstatereqtrans), the exception indicates that the server hosting the web-service is not happy with your requests encoding:

> Indicates that the peer HTTP server
>   does not support the Content-type used
>   to encode the request message. The
>   message exchange is regarded as having
>   completed unsuccessfully.

So you should check with the web-service provider concerning the content-type/encoding they expect.

A possible solution if you are using `SOAP_1_2`is to change to `SOAP_1_1` since that will alter the requests made.

Comment: More specific: http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-5286 . Solved by setting 'soap_version' => SOAP_1_1 in options, making the request get passed by text/xml instead of application/soap+xml

Comment: @MadsMobæk Brilliant, solved an identical problem I was having.

Comment: Try adding header     

Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8 for soap 1.1 and       
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8 for soap 1.2

Answer (score 7):

I am not using Zend framework, but had a similar problem with XMLHttpRequest in JavaScript. The solution was to specify the Content-Type in the SOAP request header.

```
var sr = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/">  <SOAP-ENV:Body><ns1:CelsiusToFahrenheit><ns1:Celsius>32</ns1:Celsius></ns1:CelsiusToFahrenheit></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>';
http_request = new XMLHttpRequest();
http_request.open('POST', 'http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx', true);
http_request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");
http_request.send(sr);
```

Answer (score 0):

A serious solution in one of the comments. Posting as answer for easy to identify.

Try adding header.

> Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8 for **soap 1.1**

and

> Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8 for **soap 1.2**

Credits : https://stackoverflow.com/users/2192359/atta-h