# Request Soap WSDL

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl

I've started a new project with soap request, i follow some tutorials about it and it doesn't work as well as it should.

I use this part of code for the request :

```
$client = new SoapClient("WSDL");
 
$param = array(
  "requestDate" => $date,
  "accountUID" => $id,
  "userID" => $id,
  "locale" => $local,
  "authenticationInfo" => array("password" => $pass),
  "image" => array(
                "type" => $type,
                "light" => $light,
                "source" => $source,
                                //the image has to be in base64binary
                "image" => base64_encode((fread(fopen("file", "r"), filesize("file"))))
            )
             
    );
 
try{
   //checkImage --> function on the server side
   $answer = $client->checkImage($param);
}
catch(SoapFault $e){
   echo $e;
}
```

And it give me this error :

> SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Unsupported Media Type Stack trace:

```
> #0 [internal function]: SoapClient->__doRequest('<?xml version="...', 'https://smartey...', '', 1, 0)
> #1 SoapClient->__call('checkImage', Array)
> #2 SoapClient->checkImage(Array)
```

The type of all the parameters are okay according to the documentation i've got. And the php part seems okay to me and to all the tutorials i've found.

I'm wondering if it is a header problem or something like that.

The WSDL is [here](https://smarteye.ariadnext.com/ariadnext/ws/SmartEyeWs_v1r0?wsdl 
)

If someone has an idea or a clue for this problem, i'm starting to drive crazy !

Thanks .

Answer (score 1):

The error message "unsupported media type" means that the peer HTTP server does not support the Content-type used to encode the request message. The message exchange is regarded as having completed unsuccessfully.

You should contact the web-service provider concerning the content-type/encoding they expect.

A possible solution if you are using SOAP_1_2is to change to SOAP_1_1 since that will alter the requests made.

This can be accomplished with:

```
'soap_version' => SOAP_1_1;
```

This is a duplicate of this post: 
[SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Unsupported Media Type when accessing Java web-service from PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1617857/soapfault-exception-http-unsupported-media-type-when-accessing-java-web-servi)

Comment: Hi, 
And thanks for the answer :) 

But even if i change the soap version, the error still exist !

I'll contact the web service provider concerning the content-type like you told me. 

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

server must support soap fault try this

```
try{
          //checkImage --> function on the server side
      $answer = $client->checkImage($param);
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();   
        }
```

good luck.

Comment: Hi, thks for the answer. but the getMessage() method just gave me "Unsupported Media Type".